# Emulate color scheme in Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color-reproduction

I'm trying to get this extra bright color scheme I found in a comic book scan.

I have tried with the RGB colors but usually, they don't have the white light neon-like quality to the colors.

Can this be done through a gradient or do I have to use other tools to get this color palette?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary issue you will face with practically any vector application is the variance of colors within any given area.

The orb is easy, it's primarily white/light yellow. The difficulty is the background with all its color diffusion and variance. It works because no one area is a solid color, there are tonal changes within the "glow" that lend to the notion of dispersion of the aura.

Using gradients and gradient meshes you can get somewhat of a base.

[image]
[image]

But after that, it will require detailed manual work to create more objects in order to achieve the same overall visual effect.

There is no easy or fast method to create a similar piece of artwork in a vector application. This is why, at times, pixel-based art is actually *better* for some uses.

Comment: I am trying to replicate this color scheme with a different shape, so do I manually need to change the mesh points in order to reshape after getting the initial gradient mesh?

Comment: @dfvc Generally, yes. Most meshes require manual repositioning of the points and adjustment of the handles. You can see in the above I moved some internal mesh points around.